# How can I copy files as a different user from msbuild?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I am trying to copy files to a remote server, the account I am running my build server doesn't have permissions though. How can I do it using different credentials?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try Exec task to execute RunAs.exe which would run the xcopy.exe

Comment: and how would you specify that user's password in msbuild?

Comment: you're right, I forgot RunAs _asks_ for password vs accepting it as a param :(

I guess you could do use /savecred but that would require you doing it manually the first time, on the build machine and under the credentials of the build service.

Answer (score 11):

It's best to create a quick extension of CallTarget task that uses [Impersonator](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/zetaimpersonator.aspx) by [Uwe Keim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107625/uwe-keim), like this:

```
public class Impersonate : CallTarget
{
    public string Domain { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public override bool Execute()
    {
        using (new Impersonator(this.UserName, this.Domain, this.Password))
        {
            return base.Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Then call will look like this:

```
<Target Name="DoSms">
    <....>
</Target>

<Target Name="Impersonate">
    <Impersonate Targets="DoSms" UserName="username" Password="password" Domain="domain"/>
</Target>
```

Comment: Have you actually tried this? I compiled your code and put a `<Message Text="$(USERNAME)" />` in `DoSmS`. It printed my username, not the impersonated user. I suspect that CodeProject Impersonator class may need some tweaks to work properly with MSBuild.

Comment: Yes, I did, actually this code works right now on our build server. The issue you're describing is caused by specific of MSBuild: $(USERNAME) is actually environmental variable, and they are loaded into properties once at the project start. So it will always display username of user launching project. If you want to see it working this way, you can create primitive task that prints current thread username, and call it. As you already have project with task it in linked to project file, it won't be a big deal;)